# Adding an external mongoengine model to Django-Admin views, is there a way?

Tags: django-admin, mongoengine

My django site contains an external model, provided by mongoengine.
I'd like to add a view to the admin represnting that data.
thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used django-mongoadmin with some success for this.

I was having a setup like yours, a normal Django installation with a MySQL database.. but had a few apps using mongoengine for better performance. This worked for me with simple CRUD-operations.

Link: **https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongoadmin**